# Copy data from few tables using SQL script

Tags: mysql, sql

So let's say I have a table `Car` and it has primary key `ID`, columns `BrandID` (ref to table `Brand`), `Price`, `Comment` and others.

[image].

The thing I need to do is to copy columns `Price` and `Comment` to the new table.

But also for every Car element I need to go to Brand table and get specific Brand Name depending on BrandID value and also copy it to the new table

How can I accomplish this via SQL script?

Comment: You should use something like this - CREATE TABLE ....... SELECT statement .......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the new table direct from the SELECT  statement with JOINed tbales

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE SELECT Price, Comment, name FROM car c INNER JOIN brand ON b.ID = c.BrandID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
CREATE TABLE ... SELECT statement...
```

Take a look at this mysql document for details
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html